# .NET Nancy 2 bootstrapper not firing

Tags: c#, nancy

We have a Nancy Boostrapper class like so (Structure Map):

```
public class NancyBootstrapper : StructureMapNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(IContainer existingContainer)
    {
        existingContainer.Configure(ConfigureContainer);
    }
}
```

When we run our application, this bootstrapper is found and the code hits ConfigureApplicationContainer(), all works well.

We then upgrade all Nancy packages from 1.4.1 to Nancy 2.

Upon running the application, this bootstrapper code is no longer hit.

We have isolated the issue specifically to the "Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet" package. When all Nancy packages are 2.0, this code is no longer hit. But as soon as we downgrade Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet to 1.4.1, it is successfully hit once again.

We're using the Nancy 2 "ClintEastwood" pre-release.

Has something in Nancy changed so that we can no longer use StructureMap bootstrappers?